# Exception while executing transactions using OpenEJB 4.5.0 and MySQL 5.5

Tags: transactions, ejb-3.1, openjpa, openejb

I use OpenEjb 4.5.0 and MySQL 5.5.xx with InnoDB engine.
I have a very simple stateless bean, with an injected EntityManagerFactory

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory factory
```

I'm doing a transaction as follows:

```
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
try {
  tx.begin();
  Query query = em.createNativeQuery("INSERT IGNORE INTO `myTable` (myColumn) values (1)");
  query.executeUpdate();
  tx.commit();
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
  if (tx.isActive())
    tx.rollback();
} finally {
  em.close();
}
```

With the following configurations:
**persistence.xml**:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ejbPU-ro" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>mySQLDataSource</non-jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(foreignKeys=true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(foreignKeys=true)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE,SQL=TRACE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**openejb.xml** (only data-source definition):

```
<Resource id="mySQLDataSource" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl             jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/myDb?relaxAutoCommit=true
    UserName            root
    Password
</Resource>
```

Running my small program and I'm getting the following exception:
 `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: Commit can not be set while enrolled in a transaction`
Some digging and the actual cause is that dbcp `ManagedConnection.commit` is throwing an exception if `transactionContext != null`

Any directions/hints would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Aviram

Comment: Did you check the mysql connection, you have given the port number 3307 in jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307, is it the correct port? what about if the port is given as 3306? Make sure that the user name, password and mysql driver version are right. And also try removing the **?relaxAutoCommit=true**.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is embarrassing :)
I forgot the two last lines:

```
    <Resource id="mySQLDataSource" type="DataSource">
        JdbcDriver          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        JdbcUrl             jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/myDb
        UserName            root
        Password            
        JtaManaged          false
        DefaultAutoCommit   false
    </Resource>
```